# Skip Jenkins stage when parameterized credential is unset

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to skip a stage in Jenkins when a parameterized credential is unset (in this case, an AWS account parameter). However, I seem to be unable to do so, and I'm not sure why. The stage seems to immediately start and fail without evaluating my 'when' skip condition, and later stages don't start. Here's an example:

```
parameters {
  credentials(name: 'AWS_CREDS', description: 'Skips AWS build if not specified.', credentialType: 'com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.awscredentials.AWSCredentialsImpl', required: false)
}

stage ('Build AWS') {
  when { 
    expression { params.AWS_CREDS != null }
  }
  environment {
    AWS_CREDS = credentials("${params.AWS_CREDS}")
  }
  steps {
    sh 'Use $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As I was typing the question, I stumbled my way into a solution, so I figured I'd share.

Remove the `AWS_CREDS` environment variable, change the when expression to do an empty string check (rather than a null check), and surround your steps with the `withCredentials` binding. Put together:

```
stage ('Build AWS') {
  when { 
    expression { "${params.AWS_CREDS}" != "" }
  }
  steps {
    withCredentials([[$class: 'AmazonWebServicesCredentialsBinding', credentialsId: "${params.AWS_CREDS}"]]) {
      sh 'Use $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'
    }
  }
}
```